# Object not found, error 404, when trying to use slugs

Tags: php, xampp, slug

I made a little project a while ago using slugs, everything worked fine back then. Now, when I try and open a slug, I get an "Object not found" page and a 404 error.

This is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /benc/$1 [L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /benc/index.php [L,QSA];
```

With this function I show some blogs on the homepage (with an a tag that links to a single blog or slug):

```
   function showBlogs($limit) {
        global $conn;

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT a.*, b.* FROM blogs a, slugs b WHERE b.blogID = a.idBlog");

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo '<div class="container_blogs" id="' . $row['idBlog'] . '">';
                echo '<h1 class="title_blog">' . $row['title'] . '</h1>';
                echo '<h3 class="desc_blog">' . $row['blogDesc'] . '</h3>';
                echo '<p class="text_blog">' . $row['content'] . '</p>';
                echo '<div class="link_container"><a href="http://localhost:8080/benc/' . $row['slug'] . '">' . "Read more" . '</a></div>';
                echo '</div>'; 
        }
    }
```

And this is the code for showing a single blog on a separate page:

```
global $conn;
define("SYSTEMNAME","TENPCMS1.0");
//include files after defining slug, there's a check to prevent direct execution of php files.
// include_once('template.php');
include_once('database.php');
// include_once('fetch_mysql.php');
$root = '/benc/';
//de root moet straks worden opgehaald uit mysql
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$slug = str_replace($root,"",$url);
define("SLUG", $slug);
define("DOMAIN", $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
if(SLUG == NULL ){

    function showBlog() {
        ?>

    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.
                        Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
                        nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.</h1>
    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> Nieuwe Website</a>




    <?php
    }


}
else {
    function showBlog() {
            global $conn;
            global $slug;

            $slugs = "SELECT a.* FROM blogs a, slugs b WHERE a.idBlog=b.blogId AND b.slug='$slug'";
            // $slug = "SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE idBlog = $slugs";
            $result = $conn->query($slugs);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo '<div class="container_blogs">';
                echo '<div class="blog_container_p" id="' . $row['idBlog'] . '">';
                echo '<h1 class="blog_title_p">' . $row['title'] . '</h1>';
                echo '<h3 class="blog_desc_p">' . $row['blogDesc'] . '</h3>';
                echo '<p class="blog_text_p">' . $row['content'] . '</p>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
        }


}
include_once('template.php');
```

Can anyone please tell me why I'm getting an "Object not found" error?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I feel like an idiot. Thanks to my macbook my .htaccess file got changed to _htaccess... Didn't notice that until a minute ago.

Comment: kek OS X sucks reason #10040230430243 ^^ xD